# How do I activate a toggle button in Tableview if I select a row using JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, tableview, togglebutton, listen

I have a table. It has a list of voice channels. Each row has a toggle button that can listen or mute the channel. I have two listeners, One for clicking on a row and another for selecting the toggle button. How do I change the button state if I click on a row? (For example, I click on "Voice Channel 1" and the button in that row changes to "Mute", in other words, if I select a channel, I automatically start listening to it).

```
public class VoiceChannel {
    private final StringProperty voiceChannelName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public VoiceChannel(String userName) {
        setVoiceChannelName(userName);
    }

    public final StringProperty voiceChannelNameProperty() {
        return this.voiceChannelName;
    }

    public final String getVoiceChannelName() {
        return this.voiceChannelNameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setVoiceChannelName(String voiceChannelName) {
        this.voiceChannelNameProperty().set(voiceChannelName);
    }
}
```

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TableView<VoiceChannel> voiceChannelTable = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<VoiceChannel, String> voiceChannelNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Channel Name");
        voiceChannelNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData ->    cellData.getValue().voiceChannelNameProperty());
        TableColumn<VoiceChannel, VoiceChannel> listenMuteColumn = new TableColumn<>("Listen/Mute");
        listenMuteColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(cellData.getValue()));

        ObservableSet<VoiceChannel> channels = FXCollections.observableSet();
        channels.add(new VoiceChannel("Voice Channel 1"));
        channels.add(new VoiceChannel("Voice Channel 2"));
        channels.add(new VoiceChannel("Voice Channel 3"));
        channels.add(new VoiceChannel("Voice Channel 4"));
        channels.add(new VoiceChannel("Voice Channel 5"));

        voiceChannelTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue != null) {
                System.out.println(newValue.getVoiceChannelName() + " selected");
            }
        });

        listenMuteColumn.setCellFactory(c -> new TableCell<>() {
            private final ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton();
            {
                button.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                    if (isNowSelected) {
                        System.out.println("Now listening to " + getItem().getVoiceChannelName());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(getItem().getVoiceChannelName() + " muted");
                    }
                });
                button.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(button.selectedProperty()).then("Mute").otherwise("Listen"));
                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            }

            @Override
            public void updateItem(VoiceChannel item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(button);
                }
            }
        });

        voiceChannelTable.getColumns().add(voiceChannelNameColumn);
        voiceChannelTable.getColumns().add(listenMuteColumn);

        voiceChannelTable.getItems().addAll(channels);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(voiceChannelTable), 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I can't seem to get the listeners to talk to each other. I saw an example online using Callbacks but I am not familiar with this process.

Comment: Think about handling the data behind the TableView, not the TableView itself and its Cells.  So in VoiceChannel, have a BooleanProperty called something like "isPlaying".  Then, in the updateItem() method for your ListenMute Cell you bind the ToggleButton bidirectionally to "isPlaying".  You can also manipulate the value of "isPlaying" through the TableView selection process.

Comment: It is kind of like `CheckBoxTableCell`. You could [copy the code](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.java) and change it to use a ToggleButton instead.  It won't have all of the functionality you want (as you want stuff to happen when the row is clicked as well as the button), but might help.  The implementation uses [binding in updateitem()](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.java#L358) as described by @DaveB.

Comment: I have added the BooleanProperty and changed the listenMuteColumn to TableColumn<VoiceChannel, BooleanProperty> and am updating the setIsPlaying in the voiceChannelTable listener, but am still unsure how to modify the updateItem() function. Not sure what "bidirectionally" means, i will look it up!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little application that has the core of what you're looking for, so that you can see how it would work:

```kotlin
class ChannelPlayer : Application() {
   override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
      primaryStage.scene = Scene(createContent())
      primaryStage.show()
   }

   private fun createContent(): Region = BorderPane().apply {
      val channelPlaying: StringProperty = SimpleStringProperty("")
      val channelList = createData()
      channelList.forEach {
         it.isPlaying.addListener { _ ->
            if (it.isPlaying.value) {
               channelPlaying.value = it.channelName.value
               channelList.filtered { channel -> channel != it }.forEach { channel ->
                  channel.isPlaying.value = false
               }
            }
         }
      }
      center = TableView<ChannelData>().apply {
         columns += TableColumn<ChannelData, String>("Channel Name").apply {
            cellValueFactory = Callback { p -> p.value.channelName }
         }
         columns += PlayMuteColumn()
         items = channelList
         selectionModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener { _ ->
            selectionModel.selectedItem.isPlaying.value = true
         }
      }
      bottom = VBox(5.0, Label("Now Playing:"), Label().apply {
         textProperty().bind(channelPlaying)
      })
   }

   private fun createData() = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listOf(ChannelData("Channel 1"),
                                                                       ChannelData("Channel 2"),
                                                                       ChannelData("Channel 3")))
}

class ChannelData(name: String = "") {
   val channelName: StringProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
   val isPlaying: BooleanProperty = SimpleBooleanProperty(this, name, false)
}

fun main() = Application.launch(ChannelPlayer::class.java)
```

and the TableColumn/Cell:

```kotlin
class PlayMuteColumn : TableColumn<ChannelData, BooleanProperty>() {
   init {
      cellFactory = Callback { PlayMuteCell() }
      cellValueFactory = Callback { p -> ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.value.isPlaying) }
   }

}

class PlayMuteCell : TableCell<ChannelData, BooleanProperty>() {

   private val toggleButton = ToggleButton().apply {
      textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding({ if (isSelected) "Playing" else "Muted" }, selectedProperty()))
   }

   override fun updateItem(item: BooleanProperty?, empty: Boolean) {
      itemProperty().value?.run {
         toggleButton.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional(this)
      }
      super.updateItem(item, empty)
      graphic = if ((item != null) && (item.value != null) && !empty) {
         toggleButton.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(item)
         toggleButton
      } else {
         null
      }
   }
}
```

This is Kotlin, but still JavaFX, you should be able to figure out what it's doing.

In this example `channelPlaying` and `channelList` constitute the Presentation Model.  All of the logic works off this.  In the InvalidationListener for each item in `channelList` it updates the `channelPlaying` value and flips all of the other channels off.  Where it sets the value of `channelPlaying` is where you would trigger the channel to start playing.

The TableView is just used to present the data to the user.  The `selectionModel.selectedItemProperty()` has a listener on it to flip the `isPlaying` property in that `selectedItem` to  `true`.  Then the Listener on that property will kick in, play the channel and turn off the others.

Just to keep it clean, I created a separate class for the `TableColumn` and it pulls the values and creates the cells.

The thing to note here is that the value being passed to the Cell is the BooleanProperty itself.  So the `itemProperty` of the cell contains a `BooleanProperty`.  This means that the value factory has to wrap the `BooleanProperty` in a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` so it will stay a `BooleanProperty` and not a `Boolean`.

In the Cell, there's just a ToggleButton.  It's `textProperty()` is bound to whether it's selected or not.

In `PlayMuteCell.updateItem()` is the only tricky part.  The first step is to unbind the `ToggleButton selected` property if the cell was previous populated.  Then it's bidirectionally bound to the incoming `BooleanProperty`.

The result is that when you click on the ToggleButton it also flips the `BooleanProperty` in the `ChannelData` item which triggers the Listener on it which would turn on/off the playback and do the other stuff.